# Mysql single select with dynamic columns using max

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

- Car, table holds general info
- Parts, table with name and id
- PartData, table with reference to part, columnname and columnvalue

**What I expect as result:**

```
| partname | Model  | Amount |
| Engine   | ModelA | 1      |
| Filter   | ModelB | 4      |
| Belt     | (null) | 2      |
```

What you can see is the columnname is combined with the parts, and the value is the result.
However my query returns me **only** the first and not the other too. What do I wrong?

**Some context:**
My application can be configured by a customer. So I made it possible to have dynamic columns.
For example: (I keep it simple to make question more clear)

**Car**

```
| id | name  |
| 1  | volvo |
```

**Parts**

```
| id | carid | name   |
| 1  | 1     | Engine |
| 2  | 1     | Filter |
| 3  | 1     | Belt   |
```

**Partdata**

```
| id | part_id | columnname | columnvalue
| 1  | 1       | Model      | ModelA
| 2  | 1       | Amount     | 1
| 3  | 2       | Model      | ModelB
| 4  | 2       | Amount     | 4
| 5  | 3       | Amount     | 2
```

The query I have is:

```
SELECT `parts`.`name`, 
max(case when partdata.`columnname` = 'Model' then partdata.columnvalue end) AS `Model`,
max(case when partdata.`columnname` = 'Amount' then partdata.columnvalue end) AS `Amount` 
FROM `parts` INNER JOIN `partdata` 
ON `parts`.`id` = `partdata`.`part_id` 
WHERE `carid` = 1
```

**So, why my query not returning all lines but just one?**

Edit: I use max so when no value is set or found, NULL will be returned

Comment: Because there's no group by clause

Comment: Yep...to stupid to forgot...thx for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution....by **adding GROUP BY** it works and all rows are returned correctly!